# Cтоит ли беспокоится об фрагментации индексов при использовании SSD?

Tags: sql-server, ssd

По идее, им должно пофигу на фрагментацию, так как у них нету движущихся элементов.

Хотя, все таки думается, что полная перестройка индексов все равно вносит импакт за счет перестройки дерева в более эффективное, которое не потрепали жизнью (удалением, обновлением и вставками).

Comment: имхо не пофигу - потому что проще прочитать 4кб  (страничку) и получить сразу рядом лежащие данные (например для Index scan), чем читать 4кб в одном месте, потом еще в другом для следующих данных, потом еще.. поэтому перестройка важна

Comment: Да, где-то мне попадалось, что при использовании SSD фрагментация сказывается в меньшей степени, но сказать что не влияет совсем - нельзя, из-за cache-locality.

Comment: @SultanovShamil т.е, то что SSD не нужна дефрагментация - это все враки или в контексте файловой системы она оказывает меньшее влияение?

Comment: @iluxa1810 если данные лежат рядом - это всегда хорошо. Неважно в каком контексте в фс или страниц данных в бд - они все будут быстрее работать за счёт кэшей и prefetch. Но если сравнить hdd и ssd - то для hdd фрагментация гораздо сильней бьет на перфоманс

Comment: Всем интересующимся рекомендую посмотреть, как раз об этом: [Фрагментация индексов и SSD диск](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBEHBq-wKiI)